# Custom ContextResolver<JAXBContext> not called prior to unmarshalling a request in RESTEasy 2.3.5

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, resteasy

I have a problem with a custom ContextResolver for JAXBContext after upgrading from RESTEasy version 2.3.2 to 2.3.5.

This resolver should be called prior to unmarshalling the request and prior to marshalling the response.

This worked in RESTEasy 2.3.2 but seems to be broken in 2.3.5 (insert soon to be proven wrong disclamer here).

Anyone have any ideas ?

Best regards
Benjamin

Comment: Is your `ContextResolver` annotated with `@Provider` (example:  http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.ca/2012/04/eclipselink-jpa-supports-mongodb.html) or referenced from an `Application` class (example: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html)?

Comment: It is annotated with @Provider. And as noted above it worked in 2.3.2 but not in 2.3.5 just prior to unmarshalling.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Do you have any ideas on why my custom ContextResolver isn't called prior to unmarshalling but is called prior to marshalling ?

Comment: It sounds like a RESTEasy bug, I would recommend post something on their mailing list or forum.